# Java command working on VSCode terminal, but no external terminal on mac

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

When I go to the folder with a single java file on Mac and run `javac HelloWorld.java`, the class compiles correctly, but when running it with the `java` command, I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: main
```

However, in the VSCode terminal, the identical commands work and run the program. What am I doing wrong?

java version: `"14.0.1", 2020-04-14`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Comment: How do you run the `java` command? make sure you provide a *fully qualified name* of your compiled file (include packages), and that you don't include a `.class` extension in your `java ClassName` command.

Comment: Yes, I checked all names and syntax, and I still get the same error

Comment: It is impossible that you checked and provided the correct *Fully Qualified Name* without `.class` extension, and it doesn't run, considering, of course, that you have a `public static void main(String[] args) {}` method in your main class.

Comment: What does `type java` say?

Comment: Can you post the `java` command you used and the code for `HelloWorld.java`?

Comment: We can't help you if you don't post the java command.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible. As you described, your java file named 'HelloWorld.java', and you compiled it through command 'javac HelloWorld.java'. But the error message shows:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: main
```

This means the java interpreter is looking for a class named 'main', not the 'HelloWorld'. So what's the command you had token? If you take command 'java HelloWorld' and the java interpreter can't find 'HelloWorld' class, you should get this error message:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld
```